# How to pass auth token from Parse SDK to Fabric TwitterKit?

Tags: ios, twitter, parse-platform, pfuser

I log in my Twitter users using `+[PFTwitterUtils loginWithBlock:]` method from Parse SDK. To get user profile picture I login second time with `-[Twitter logInWithCompletion:]` method from Fabric TwitterKit. Is there any way to pass auth token from Parse SDK to TwitterKit and **login only once**?

There is a way to export auth token and auth token secret from Parse by using `PF_Twitter` class from Parse SDK. It looks like it should be possible create a TwitterKit session by using `-[TWTRSession initWithSessionDictionary:]`, but [Twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios-reference/twtrsession) says nothing about dictionary format and I can't get it working.

Answer (score 3):

**Parse**

When the user is logged in using Parse's TwitterUtils you get this method called `twitter`. Right now I'm using Swift, so with `PFTwitterUtils.twitter()` you'll get all the data needed. I guess it should be `[PFTwitterUtils twitter];` in Objective-C.

The class is `PF_Twitter` on Parse.

**Fabric TwitterKit**

Once you get that object you'll get access to `authToken` and `authTokenSecret` for the current user.
Then you gotta use this method from TwitterKit (Note: This will be deprecated in the future, look at the **UPDATE** at the bottom):

Objective-C:

`[Twitter sharedInstance]`

`logInWithExistingAuthToken:authTokenSecret:completion:`

Swift:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithExistingAuthToken(authToken, authTokenSecret: authTokenSecret, completion: { (session, error) -> Void in
})
```

If everything went well, this will return the current session.

**Documentation:**

*Parse:*

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFTwitterUtils.html#//api/name/twitter

PF_Twitter - https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PF_Twitter.html

*Fabric:*

https://docs.fabric.io/appledocs/Twitter/Classes/Twitter.html#//api/name/logInWithExistingAuthToken:authTokenSecret:completion:

**UPDATE**:

I just noticed that `logInWithExistingAuthToken` will be deprecated. So the best way to do this is using the `TWTRSessionStore`'s `saveSessionWithAuthToken` method:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.saveSessionWithAuthToken(authToken, authTokenSecret: authTokenSecret, completion: { (session, error) -> Void in

                    })
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. This should be accepted as the correct answer.